# Can symfony DateType form fields allow alternate formats?

Tags: forms, symfony

In a symfony4 form I have a DateType field that works great and I like the validation and auto handling of error messages that come with it.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dob', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'M/d/yy',
        ]);
}
```

What I'd like is to be able to allow the user to use either 2-digit or 4-digit years and have both pass validation.

It seems that one tedious way to do this would be to modify this particular form element within the Request object before passing to the `handleRequest()` method in my controller, but this would be messy and tightly bound to my code.

A really nice way (that does not exist) would be to have something like another option `'alternate_format' => 'M/d/yyyy'`.

Does anyone have a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I've solved my problem with some client-side javascript. In case anyone else needs something similar, my date field is a date of birth and if I accept the limitation that I don't have anyone over 100 years old then this solutions works well for my purposes. [edit: this limitation is true only if you force a 2-digit year. If you set the format to a 4-digit year and then use JavaScript to massage to the same, then there are no such limitations. The script below does assume that dates cannot be in the future, which is appropriate for a date of birth field.]

In my form, I added a class to my field and assume the format should have a 4-digit year:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dob', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'M/d/yyyy',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-dob'],
        ])
}
```

Then on the client side I have this little snippet that runs on submit:

```
$('.js-save-button').on('click', function() {
    // convert 2-digit years to 4-digit version in dob field
    $('.js-dob').each(function() {
        let date = new Date($(this).val());
        if (date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date)) {
            if (date > new Date()) {
                date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 100);
            }
        }
        $(this).val(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
    });
});
```